# Dir command : How to show only the date created file and created file .txt out of it

Tags: cmd

I know that `dir /b` shows only the file name. and `dir /b /o:-d` shows only the file name and sort by it by last date.

Is it possible to call dir, that only shows the file created date only (not showing sizes or names) and created a .txt files out of it?

the expected result is like this

```
28/06/2019 13:13 
28/06/2019 12:12
28/06/2019 11:11 
....
```

Comment: not with `dir` alone, but you can postprocess it's output with a `for /f` loop: `for /f "tokens=1,2" %a in ('dir /a-d /o-d') do @echo %a %b|find ":"'` (command line syntax. For use in a batch file use `%%` instead of `%`)

Comment: this line [ for /f "tokens=1,2" %a in ('dir /a-d /o-d') do @echo %a %b |find ":"'] is working. thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Either at the beginning or at the very end: `>filename.txt (for /f ....find ":")` or `(for /f ... find":")>filename.txt`

Comment: but whre do i place the command [ >filename.txt ] for creating files that i want? ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do that with `dir` alone, but you can postprocess it's output with a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %a in ('dir /a-d /o-d') do @echo %a %b|find ":"'
```

Note: this is command line syntax. For use in a batch file use `%%` instead of `%`

`dir /a-d` shows files only (no folders).
`|find ":"` shows only lines that have a colon (as in time 12:34), suppressing the summary lines.
`"tokens=1,2"` takes the first two "words" (delimited by spaces or tabs), so the date (first token, goes to `%a`) and the time (second token, goes to `%b`).

Answer (score 4):

The [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) displays the last modification date/time as per default. To change to the creation date/time you need to add the `/T:C` option. To return the date/time values only use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) in a similar way as shown in [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56809325):

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1,2 eol= " %I in ('dir /A:-D /O:-D /T:C *.*') do @echo/%I  %J
```

The `eol` option is set to a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in order to exclude lines that begin with that character, because this applies to the introduction and summary lines, which we do not want. This method does not rely on filtering by a locale-dependent character.

(If you want to use this code in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), change every `%` to `%%`.)

---

For the last modification date you can simply omit the `/T:C` part. Alternatively you could use a simple [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) if you do not need the date/time values to be sorted (descendingly):

```cmd
for %I in (*.*) do @echo/%~tI
```

The [`~t` modifier](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) returns the last modification date/time.

Regard that both of the above approaches return the date/time values in a locale-dependent manner.

Comment: I also considered a simple `for %I in (*) do @echo %~ti`, but that isn't sorted. I like how you use the `eol` option to skip the unwanted lines.