# How to execute 2 command dir line in command prompt using bat. files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

These 2 command lines in command prompt works well:

```
dir /b /o:- > listname.csv

(for /f "tokens=1,2" %a in ('dir /a-d /o-d') do @echo %a %b|find ":") >listdate.csv
```

But when I'm trying to make a `.bat` file of it, it doesn't create those files (`listname.csv` and `listdate.csv`).

The `.bat` file content is supposed to be the same script as I wrote in command prompt, right? Or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Well, in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56803102) it is mentioned in a comment and in every answer that you need to use `%%` instead of `%` in a batch file for `for` meta-variables; type `for /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the help message very carefully...

Comment: The first line of your code will run, although there is no sort order specified after `/O:-` (so I don't really know what order `dir` uses then, but it'll work)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIthin a batch file, the `metavariables` (those established by the `for` command, in this case `%a` and `%b`) need to have their `%` signs doubled.

```
(for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('dir /a-d /o-d') do echo %%a %%b|find ":") >listdate.csv
```

There appears to be no reason why the `listname.csv` file would not be generated.

Comment: thank you. the file listdate.csv is generated. but the output of the file is not the same as i requested using cmd. the command-to-be-executed (in this case is..   |find ":" ) not working

Comment: found the solution. the '^' must be double, use '^^' instead of '^'. thank you for your help sir.